# cryptdb mysql proxy not working

Tags: mysql, database, encryption

I installed cryptDB  and it is running from the shell and give outputs.The data is stored as encrypted in the db.But when i use mysql proxy to run it,the data is plane that is no encryption is performed.Please help me how the data is encrypted and stored using mysql proxy.I need to know how the key is entered to encrypt data

Answer (score -1):

It might be helpful if you describe in detail what you did and what you saw. Anyway, I have been working with CryptDB to do some tests. I used mysqlproxy, which is the second method to test/run CryptDB stated in the **README** file. I don't think we can see encrypted data when using the proxy, because when we select from database, the result has already been decrypted. Therefore what we see is plain text.

I guess when you say *'running from shell'* you might mean running the **cdb_test**, the first approached mentioned in **README**. Yes I think in this way, we can see the encrypted data.

When you create tables and insert data, you might want to go back to where the mysqlproxy is running to check whether it shows you the encrypted data.